# How to pick constants for Big Theta Notation.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

I'm having a problem solving these and understanding big theta notation in general.

> i.) Show that if $a(n) = 5n^3 - 97n^2 + 6n - 3$, then $a(n) = \Theta\left(n^3\right)$.
>
> ii.) Suppose that $a(n)$, $b(n)$, $c(n)$, $d(n)$ are positive sequences with $a(n) = \Theta\left(b(n)\right)$ and $c(n) = \Theta\left(d(n)\right)$. Show that if $b(n) \leq d(n)$ holds for all $n$, then $a(n) + c(n) = \Theta\left(d(n)\right)$.

For the first one, I was trying to find the best possible values for $c_1$ and $c_2$ but it always goes out of the rules as $n$ starts growing. For the second I guess I just really don't know where to start from. Any explanation or hint would be helpful really.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry my bad. I fixed it.

Comment: The "best" possible values for $c_1, c_2$ is really going to depend on what you mean by best. There is some $N$ such that for all $n>N$
$$4.999 n^3 \le a(n) \le 5.001n^3 $$ and these constants can get closer and closer to $5$ as we let $N$ get bigger.

Comment: Does your text offer a rigorous definition of big theta?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

> $f(n)\in\Theta\left(g(n)\right)$ if $$0 < \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} <\infty$$

Let $f(n) = 5n^3 - 97n^2 + 6n - 3$, and $g(n) = n^3$. Can you find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$?